# WebLogic Server internal server error

Tags: web-server, java, weblogic

when I deploy a project in `Apache Tomcat 6.0` it's working fine. When I deploy the same project in `weblogic server 10.3` it's showing an error like below:

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

javax.servlet.ServletException: [HTTP:101249][weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@ae43b8 - appName: '_appsdir_ab_dir', name: 'ab', context-path: '/ab', spec-version: 'null']: Servlet class FirstServlet for servlet FirstServlet could not be loaded because the requested class was not found in the classpath . java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: FirstServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project has been built with a JDK whose version is higher than WebLogic supports. 51.0 designates JDK 7, but Weblogic 10.3.1 (for example, insert your version here) supports JDK 5 at most.

You must either update Weblogic or make your project compatible to a earlier Java Version.

You'll find more information about WebLogic 10.3's compatibility on Oracle's homepage: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/compatibility/compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using older version of Weblogic eg. (10.3.x)and **higher version of java** eg (jdk1.7.x).
The solutions are
1.If possible update your Weblogic by higher version (OR)
2.compile your project with jdk 1.6 
   Go to IDE (eg.Eclipse) > right click on project>Properties>select java compiler > **change compiler compliance 1.7 to 1.6**>Apply OK >Go to project>clean and build >
*now deploy it .It will work definitely.* :)

Comment: You will do much better if you do not choose three-year-old questions with existing satisfactory answers that are pretty much repeated by your post. You can visit the [Unanswered](https://serverfault.com/unanswered) pane to have a look at fresher and more important questions.